# How to prevent IntelliJ to stop continuing double-slash comments on the next line?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

**Short version**

When pressing `<enter>` at the end of a `//` comment, Intellij sometimes decides to continue the `//` comment on the next line.  How can I prevent that?  Is there a setting somewhere to disable this automation?

**Long version**

There is a thing I do regularily, it is to break a long expression with a double-slash.

Let's say I have a line like

```
boolean isHex = c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'f';
```

and I want to split it like that

```
boolean isHex = c >= '0' && c <= '9' //
        || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F' //
        || c >= 'a' && c <= 'f';
```

Note that I want the final `//` in order to prevent any formatter to join the lines again.

So I insert a double-slash-return after the `'9'`, by pressing `//<enter>`.  But Intellij will auto-continue the comment on the next line.

```
boolean isHex = c >= '0' && c <= '9' //
// || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'f';
```

It forces me to uncomment and reindent the line manually.

I want Intellij to *not* continue the comment on the next line and optionally indent my code:

```
boolean isHex = c >= '0' && c <= '9' //
        || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'f';
```

So I want to disable this "continue // comment after `<enter>`" feature.  Is it possible?  I haven't found any setting related to that.

Comment: It sounds like you are using a workaround to prevent code-formatters from messing up with your code formatting.  In the process, you are now  having to do another work-around to have the IDE not do something that would be beneficial for most (except in your case, it isn't). My gut feel when I have to do a work-around for a work-around is that I am (perhaps) heading in the wrong direction.  Firstly, comments at the end of a line a discouraged by many code-quality analysis tools. Then, formatting should be defined externally to the IDE (with a file) so that it can be shared by/with others.

Comment: You can turn of locally the formatter with a comment before and after the region with -by default disabled- `// @formatter:off`/`// @formatter:on` comments (search the settings for `Enable formatter markers in comments`)

Comment: @ochi  I believe it is a good thing to be able to force line breaks in meaningful places.  The formatter sometimes does a poor job at choosing a good place.  The // isn't very pretty but is the best I have found.  The // is also necessary to prevent an external formatter to mess up the code.  My feeling is that I work against deficiencies in the IDE.  When I insert //<enter>, Intellij should remember that the end of the line was actual code and should retain it as code, not as a comment.

Comment: Definitely a personal opinion here but I find that workarounds to formatting personal preferences are not the job of an IDE.  How is it to distinguish from, I want to comment out this code vs I want to continue using this code (but I put a `//` in front of it)? For example, you could just simply break line first and then add the `//` at the end of the line or add the `@formatter:off` annotation.... (which these unique, personal use-cases are for) - I am not sure the IDE is meant to read our minds (yet ;) )

Comment: It works well in Eclipse.  Eclipse lets me add the //'s where I need them and doesn't try to guess when I need them and add them when it decides I do.  I only want to disable this particular automation, many automations can be disabled, why not this one?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you are going to get is to define a macro to insert a new line and remove the comment and then bind that macro to a suitable key.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings → Code Style → Java → Wrapping and Braces** and check "Line breaks" under "Keep when reformatting". This will make IntelliJ's formatter respect any manual line breaks, even if they contradict other formatting rules.

Comment: Thank you for the hint.  It doesn't answer the question but gives an alternative to using //.  It could help some but in my case that doesn't work because the code style is imposed by my company.

Comment: I think that option should still prevent IntelliJ from moving `//` to the next line, right?

Comment: I just tried.  It doesn't.  Not in IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.2 on OS X.